# What can I use instead of DetectHaarCascade?

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/462527/Camera-Face-Detection-in-Csharp-using-Emgu-CV-and) but it seems that on every line I am getting some annoying error.

I checked [the documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/b71ffd87-1652-8dc2-eb04-7a37f916b6cb.htm) and can see that `DetectHaarCascade` is marked as **obsolete**, but it doesn't suggest any alternative.

Can anyone please advise on how I can achieve this? Surely they havne't just removed the functionality altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Haar Cascade is now in the CascadeClassifier class in EmguCV 3.4.1. The example in the EmguCV distribution has been updated to use a CascadeClassifier. I suggest you look at the examples in 3.4.1 for a better way to do face recognition.
Doug